# Deriving the form of the Exponential Integral from a given integral

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

The Wikipedia entry on [Asymptotic Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) outlines a detailed example, where it refers to the fact that the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-w/t}}{1-w} \, dw
\end{equation}
understood as a Cauchy Principal value, can be expressed in terms of the exponential integral
\begin{equation}
\text{Ei}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^t}{t} \, dt
\end{equation}
in the form
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-w/t}}{1-w} \, dw = e^{-1/t} \, \text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)
\end{equation}

I tried to fill in the details for myself, using various changes of variables, but somehow I manage to make a mistake each time because I cannot get to the desired form. How can I see the connection between these integrals ?

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the variable from $t$ to $z=\tfrac{1-w}{t}$ you get:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-w/t}}{1-w}dw=e^{-1/t}\int_{-\infty}^{1/t}\frac{e^z}{z}dz=e^{-1/t}\mathrm{Ei}(1/t)$$